# Failed to register a ServiceWorker (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps, next-pwa

i have created a sample next project i use this command : npx create-next-app 
i install next-pwa after that i configure next.config,create manifest.json and _document.js
in project directory

this is my next.config.js :

```
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");

module.exports = withPWA({
reactStrictMode:true,
pwa: {
dest: "public",
register: true,
skipWaiting: true,
disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
}
```

});

my _document.js :

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
render() {
    return (
        <Html>
            <Head>
                <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icon.png"></link>
                <meta name="theme-color" content="#fff" />
            </Head>
            <body>
            <Main />
            <NextScript />
            </body>
        </Html>
    );
}
}

export default MyDocument;
```

after run : npm run build and npm start
i saw this error :
[image]

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug. Please, downgrade `next-pwa` version to `5.5.4` and it should work.